# How can i get the common field in table with id

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need a sql command that do the following things:
For exemple,

```
PhonesTBL   HistoryTBL
---------   --------
PhoneID     UserID
PhoneType   PhoneID

PhonesTBL   HistoryTBL
---------   ----------
3,Samsung   100,3
4,Samsung   100,4
5,Apple     100,5
```

I need a sql command that gives me the most common PhoneType by any PhoneID in my Tables.
The query, on my example will reurn Samsung for userID 100.
becuase samsung is the most common Type.
Im using access and c# but i need the sql query to work.
Looking For Help, Ohad.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Please include some sample data.  I see a few edge cases which need to be addressed.  Also, please tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What DBMS are you using? In Oracle for instance this is just `select stats_mode(phonetype) from phonestbl`. PostgreSQL has `mode() within group()` for this. Most other DBMS don't have such function at all.

Comment: What do you want to do in case of ties (e.g. four phones, two with type 3, two with type 4)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your question doesn't actually make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"select PhonesTBL.PhoneType
 from PhonesTBL 
 Inner join HistoryTBL on PhonesTBL.PhoneID=HistoryTBL.PhoneID
 where UserID={0}
 group by PhoneType
 order by count(*) desc
"
```

Did This, Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(sum)  
FROM (SELECT COUNT(PhoneType) as sum 
      FROM PhonesTBL  
      GROUP BY Quantity)  
AS result;
```

Please try above query. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: i need this query again becuase i updated the question tho, but thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
select distinct(h.userid), p.PhoneType
from PhonesTBL p
join HistoryTBL h on h.PhoneID = p.PhoneID
where p.phonetype in (select phonetype 
                    from PhonesTBL 
                    group by phonetype
                    having count(phonetype) =  (SELECT MAX(c) FROM
                                              (SELECT COUNT(phonetype) AS c
                                               FROM PhonesTBL
                                               GROUP BY phonetype) AS TBL1))
```

Comment: i need this query again becuase i updated the question tho, but thanks for reply